# Box Cox transformed my data, now how to use it in my mixed model?

Tags: data-transformation, sas

I have Box Cox transformed my data in SAS, but I am unsure how to use the transformed data in my mixed model.

Do I output it to a new file, and use that in my model statement, or do I need to incorporate the proc transreg statement into my proc mixed?  Details are appreciated as I am new to SAS.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to base a transform on the original data BUT you want to use the residuals from a reasonable model to determine that. The Gaussian assumptions ALL relate to the error process NOT the residuals around a simple mean which is what you are implicitely doing.